# What software packages is Microsoft Outlook included with?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

Microsoft Outlook  doesn't seem to be included in my Office package. Is it part of Windows?

How do I get it? I dislike it for e-mail (and I may have uninstalled it as some point), but I need it to read the notes on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can get Outlook with certain versions of Microsoft Office.

From [**this chart**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2010-which-suite-is-right-for-you-FX101825640.aspx), you can see that for Office 2010, you have to buy Office Home and Business or higher in order to get Outlook.

[image: office 2010 comparison chart]

#### Older versions:

- [Office 2007 comparison chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2007-comparison-table-FX101812256.aspx)
- [Office 2003 comparison table](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/product-review/microsoft-office-2003-editions-compared)

Comment: Just for completeness: He doesn't have to buy Office, he can also get Outlook in a standalone version (see my post below), which is probably a cheaper solution.

Answer (score 1):

If Outlook is included in the Office suite you already have, then you can add it back in by changing the installed features. Go to the control panel's add/remove programs, and find Office on the list. Choose to "change" the installation, then in the Office installer choose to Add/Remove features. This will present you with a list of packages included in the suite, and you can add Outlook back in by selecting its dropdown and choosing "Run from my computer".

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook#Outlook_2013), Microsoft Outlook is included in Office 2013, except Home & Student edition.